# Shopify: blog.articles doesn't show all articles when in tagged view

Tags: shopify, liquid

I've had to create my own version of a blog archive using tags in Shopify because of course Shopify doesn't have a built in archive.

In the sidebar, I loop through `blog.articles` then write the year or month of each article using `if` and `unless` statements if it hasn't already been written out. It all works and looks great on the blog index page, but if I click on one of the months to go to the page for that tag (for example, /blogs/news/tagged/december-2017) then only December 2017 appears in the sidebar.

I don't understand why this is happening, I thought `blog.articles` contained **all** articles in a blog regardless of tag filtering. Any help on how to loop through everything regardless of filter would be a big help.

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting the blog on the sidebar?  You may have to do something like

```
{% assign blog = blogs['handle'] %}
```

where the handle is the handle of the specific blog you want.

(it's likely being automatically set on the blog page)