# Shopify / Liquid - Access articles outside of current tag search/filter

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have a Shopify blog, in this example called *blog1*. I would like to use liquid to access **all** articles within that blog, whilst filtering by a specific tag.

For instance, supposing I am at the following URL (i.e. tagging by articles with the tag "chicken").

`www.website.com/blogs/blog1/tagged/chicken`

When I do `{% for article in blog.articles %}{{ article.title }}{% endfor %}`, it only outputs articles which have the tag "chicken". I understand that this is normal and expected behaviour for filtering, but I want to know how I can still somehow loop through **all** articles from this page.

I have looked at [Shopify: blog.articles doesn't show all articles when in tagged view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48790462/shopify-blog-articles-doesnt-show-all-articles-when-in-tagged-view) but their question is slightly different, and the only answer is not a valid solution in this case: `{% for article in blog['blog1'].articles %}{{article.url}}{%endfor%}` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refer to the global `blogs` object and the specific handle of the blog.

So the answer you showed is correct but your implementation is not. The global blogs object is written like so `blogs['handle']` and not `blog['handle']`.

So in your case it will be like so:

```
{% for article in blogs['blog1'].articles %}
  {{article.url}}
{% endfor %}
```

Just add the missing `s` in the blog object.